# Pipe symbol | unexpected in FOR /F loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, pipe

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %i IN (query session | FINDSTR /i "console") DO set "ID=%i"
```

I am getting an error `| was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: *N. B.:* In a batch file, you need to double the `%`-signs (type `for /?` into Command Prompt)…

Answer (score 2):

Two very simple mistakes to avoid.

First by reading `For /?` use 'single quotes' for commands.

Secondly ^escape the |

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %i IN ('query session ^| FINDSTR  /i "console"') DO set "ID=%i"
```

Reminder as mentioned by @aschipfl in comment use doubled %% for both of your i's in a batch file or file.cmd

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should always read the usage information for a command utility before you use it. Had you done so, you would have noted that as you are specifically trying to isolate a line with the session name `console`, you could have used `query session console` instead of the less robust `query session | FINDSTR /i "console"`. Of course, using the more appropriate command would mean that you do not have any issue with a horizontal bar, *(pipe)*.

If you wanted, you could also `skip` the first, *(header)*, line, and if you are certain, that your ID will always be the third whitespace separated token, you could then use:

From the Command Prompt, ([cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)):

```sh
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=3" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\query.exe Session Console 2^>NUL') Do @Set "ID=%G"
```

Or from a batch file, ([batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)):

```sh
@For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=3" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\query.exe Session Console 2^>NUL') Do @Set "ID=%%G"
```